# i can't figure how to turn an html page to an xhtml(jsf) , when i run the page i get no tag was defined for name: input

Tags: jsf

im trying to implement jsf for a login page , when i run it it give me this :[/login.xhtml @33,49 <h:input> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: input] avec la cause
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /login.xhtml @33,49 <h:input> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: input

login.xhtml =

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  
  
  
  <h:head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Web Application | todo</title>
  <meta name="description" content="app, web app, responsive, admin dashboard, admin, flat, flat ui, ui kit, off screen nav" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Web Application _ todo_files/app.v2.css" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Web Application _ todo_files/font.css" type="text/css"/>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="js/ie/respond.min.js" cache="false"></script> <script src="js/ie/html5.js" cache="false"></script> <script src="js/ie/fix.js" cache="false"></script> <![endif]-->

  </h:head>
  
  <body>

  <section id="content" class="m-t-lg wrapper-md animated fadeInUp">
     <a class="nav-brand" href="index.html">WELCOME</a> 
     <div class="row m-n">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 m-t-lg">
           <section class="panel">
              <header class="panel-heading text-center"> Sign in </header>
              <h:form action="index.html" class="panel-body">
                 <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label">username</label>
                  <h:inputText type="email" placeholder="username" class="form-control"/> </div>
                 <div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                  <h:inputSecret type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"/> </div>
                 <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                  <h:input type="checkbox"/> Keep me logged in </label> </div>
                 <a href="#" class="pull-right m-t-xs"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
                 <h:commandButton  value="Sign in" class="btn btn-info"/>
                  
                 <div class="line line-dashed"></div>
                 
                 <div class="line line-dashed"></div>
                 <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>Do not have an account?</small></p>
                 <a href="signup.html" class="btn btn-white btn-block">Create an account</a> 
              </h:form>
           </section>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
       </body>

  
  </html>
```

Comment: You need to use `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` for a checkbox. Next thing is to fix your form action. Read some starter tutorials first. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: .. and use an IDE with code completion, much better than having to guess tag names.